# How to fix a unexisting Reactive Forms error

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm building a form but, for whatever reason, the compiler is complaining about it.

Can anybody spot something wrong here?

This is what I get:

> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'email'
>
> ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'password'

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { EmailLoginComponent } from './email/email-login.page';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.page';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { RegisterComponent } from './registration/register.page';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        EmailLoginComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        RegisterComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        RouterModule.forChild([
            { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'emailLogin' , component: EmailLoginComponent },
            { path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent }
        ]),
        ReactiveFormsModule
    ],
    exports: [],
    providers: [],
})
export class LoginModule {}
```

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-register',
    templateUrl: './register.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    platform: string;
    registerForm: FormGroup;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.registerForm = new FormGroup({
            email: new FormControl(''),
            password: new FormControl('')
        });
    }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onRegisterUser()">
    <ion-item lines="full" color="secondary">
        <ion-input placeholder="Email" type="email" formControlName="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item lines="full" color="secondary">
        <ion-input placeholder="Password" type="password" formControlName="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code into an ionic stackblitz project and was unable to reproduce your issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ojdypw

Maybe there is something there that can help you.

Comment: Hey @Quaz4 I know right? It's really really weird... I don't get it. :/. But thanks thou